# Issue with Redirect uri with different root domains in Azure App registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, auth0, onedrive

I am facing an issue where in my Azure app registration as I would like to have 2 different redirect URIs. I have registered platform as web app in Azure and I am using Auth0 for authentication.

For this purpose I have added my Auth0 callback URI: `https://dev-xxxxxxxxx.us.auth0.com/login/callback` to handle Auth0 requirements.

I am also integrating MS Onedrive Filepicker within my application. I am using the OneDrive js SDK 8.0. For this purpose I require to use a redirect URI again. But in this case, it has to be my application URL i.e. `https://{my-domain}.io/detail`

I am conflicted as when I try to add my own domain, MS Azure throws this error:  `Error detail: Redirect URIs must have a common root domain.`

If it is not allowed to have different root domains under a single app registration, how do I proceed to support both Auth0 as well as Onedrive filepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Azure app registrations one cannot register redirect URI with different domains which is very weird considering the fact that google and facebook integrations allow it. So I had to create two separate app registrations.

Answer (score 1):

Tried the different redirect urls with different domains in my case;

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/1xx0/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xx&client_secret=x1&redirect_uri= xxxhttps://www.example.com/auth/callback&scope=api://x/.default&response_type=code
```

When I gave different root domain :
`https://example.com/auth/callback`
`https://www.example.com/auth/callback

I got error for redirect uri mismatch

[image]

If you have several subdomains and your scenario requires that, upon successful authentication, you redirect users to the same page from which they started, using a state parameter might be helpful.

Please check [Redirect URI (reply URL) restrictions - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#use-a-state-parameter)

If we are having  example1.csdom.com and example2.csdom.com as redirect URIs, first domain “`https://csdom.com`” as a redirect URI should be added and then add the sub-domains, like :

1. `https://csdom.com`
2. `https://example1.csdom.com`
3. `https://example2.csdom.com`

Then the authentication can be successful

[image]

[image]

**Make sure to give Redirect Uris with common root domain.**

**Reference:**  [Add two Redirect URIs with same root domain (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0314faea-3180-4933-b203-392803588790/add-two-redirect-uris-with-same-root-domain?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

Comment: https://example.com/auth/callback is compulsory for Auth0 integration. My issue is that I want to add Redirect Uris with different root domains. The Auth0 redirect URI and my own website domain. Google cloud console and facebook dev allow this in their app registrations. But microsoft doesn't, why is that?